# Unable to import modules from relative path

Tags: python, import, module

I have a problem for importing modules from relative path with Python. I tried all I found on the web. Here is my directory structure:

```
starcipher/
    __init__.py
    caesar.py
    tests/
        __init__.py
        test_caesar.py
```

As you can tell, the `tests/` directory contains all my unit tests. The `test_caesar.py` uses the class defined in `caesar.py`. Here is my files:

`caesar.py`:

```
class Caesar:
    # Blabla
```

`tests/test_caesar.py`:

```
import unittest
from ..caesar import Caesar

# I also tried:
from caesar import Caesar
from starcipher.caesar import Caesar
from . import Caesar
from .. import Caesar

# Nothing works.

class TestCaesar(unittest.TestCase):
   # Blabla
```

I have this error each time:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_caesar.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ..caesar import Caesar
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

**EDIT**

Here is how I run my unit test:

- In the root directory: `python -m unittest discover tests/`
- Or in the `tests/` directory: `python test_caesar.py`
- Or even: `python -m unittest`

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to Pocin, removing the `__init__.py` file from the `tests/` directory solved the problem!

Thank you.

Comment: You need to show exactly how you are running that test file.

Comment: Yesterday I was struggling with exactly same thing (only with py.test). In my case, removing `__init__.py` from the tests/ directory fixed it for me

Comment: @Pocin Yeah! Removing `__init__.py` from the `tests/` worked! Thanks :)

Comment: Good to hear that! I was going insane because I could not figure it out. Still not exactly sure why that works tho :)

Answer (score 0):

Just so the solution is nicely visible, the fix is to delete `tests/__init__.py` file.

However I am not really sure why that works and It would be great if someone could provide explanation.